# Xcode console text

Tags: iphone, xcode

i am getting the error

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:12:55 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:13:19 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:13:29 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:13:32 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:13:53 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:14:03 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:14:05 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:14:05 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:14:05 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:14:06 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:14:11 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:14:27 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:14:39 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

[Session started at 2011-04-13 18:14:52 +0530.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.

can anyone explain what this mean?

Comment: possbile duplicate question [iPhone: Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779115/iphone-failed-to-launch-simulated-application-unknown-error)

Comment: and another possible duplicate [Xcode error: Failed to launch simulated application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822972/xcode-error-failed-to-launch-simulated-application)

Answer (score 0):

Restart Xcode and the iOS simulator.  If that doesn't clear things up, you might have to rebooted your system.

Comment: i tried it already. my application runs but when i re-build it ,gives the same error. is there any problem in my database connectivity?
data in m database is not reflecting in my table view.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but a google search turns [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822972/xcode-error-failed-to-launch-simulated-application) up as the first hit. If you did look at that, it would be helpful to say something to that affect. My summary of that link is it seems to be a bit of  "bail out" error where "something" is wrong with your project/config. Xcode sometimes flakes out in various ways (like most IDE's). First thing I usually do is close xcode, delete the build folder, re-open and do a clean build. If that doesn't do it, check out a prior version from source control and make sure that's ok. If it is, try to see what changed between the revisions. If you determine it's the project config, maybe you can fix it with a merge of changed classes from your working set with project config from source control. (etc, etc,...)

Comment: i tried it already.
my application runs but when i re-build it ,gives the same error.
is there any problem in my database connectivity?

thanks for help..