# How to "Clear File History" of Info.plist on Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator

I have problems for run the project in simulator and here [Xcode error: Failed to launch simulated application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822972/xcode-error-failed-to-launch-simulated-application) , seems to be the solution. The problem is that i can't find the "Clear File History" option in XCode 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Product>Clean`

or

`Shift+Command+K`

Is what I believe you're looking for. `Clean` should be the same thing as `Clear File History`